# Bluetooth works one way only

Tags: java, android

I am very new to android and java so be gentle :)
I'm trying to connect two phones via bloototh.
i am making both phones to listen of incoming calls by creating serversocket, then initializing connection from one phone (as a client). funny part is that when I try to make my LG (android version 2.3.4) to connect HTC (android 2.2.1) everything works fine, but when i try to make HTc phone to connect as a client i get no result. Debugger shows that HTC fails at   mmSocket.connect(); and executes catch (IOException connectException). My code is basicly copy/paste from android bluetooth tutorial. Any suggestions why phones behaves differently? Connect thread:

```
    private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;

    public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
        // Use a temporary object that is later assigned to mmSocket,
        // because mmSocket is final
        BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
        mmDevice = device;
        // Get a BluetoothSocket to connect with the given BluetoothDevice
        try {
            // MY_UUID is the app's UUID string, also used by the server code
            tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
        } catch (IOException e) { }
        mmSocket = tmp;
    }

    public void run() {
        // Cancel discovery because it will slow down the connection
        BtAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        try {
            // Connect the device through the socket. This will block
            // until it succeeds or throws an exception
            mmSocket.connect(); **HTC phones fails here and goes to CATCH block**
            // make info message
            Message msg = mainHandler.obtainMessage();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            String btnTxt = "Connected";
            bundle.putString("myKey", btnTxt);
            msg.setData(bundle);
            mainHandler.sendMessage(msg);
        } catch (IOException connectException) {
            // Unable to connect; close the socket and get out
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException closeException) { }
            return;
        }
        // Do work to manage the connection (in a separate thread)
        ConnectedThread conThread = new ConnectedThread(mmSocket);
        conThread.start();
    }

    /** Will cancel an in-progress connection, and close the socket */
    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) { }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be in issue with

`tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);`

on your HTC 2.21 device. Check what features the HTC device's Bluetoth adapter supports, that could be related to why it is failing with your program.

> "Use this socket only if an authenticated socket link is possible.
>   Authentication refers to the authentication of the link key to prevent
>   man-in-the-middle type of attacks. For example, for Bluetooth 2.1
>   devices, if any of the devices does not have an input and output
>   capability or just has the ability to display a numeric key, a secure
>   socket connection is not possible. In such a case, use {#link
>   createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord}. For more details, refer to
>   the Security Model section 5.2 (vol 3) of Bluetooth Core Specification
>   version 2.1 + EDR."
>
> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord%28java.util.UUID%29